# can't redirect to profil url in angular5

Tags: angular, angular5, frontend

working with a simple app in angular5 , i have a header containing 'profil' link , i'm trying to redirect the user to the profilComponent when clicking on the link but nothing happends , instead of that the user get logged out of the app .

i'm Using jwt for authentication .

This is how the structure of the project looks like :

[image]

for profil components it exists inside views directory :

[image]

i have already added ProfilRoutingModule in the profil module , and also i have added profil module in   app.routing.ts :

```
{
    path: 'profil',
    loadChildren: './views/profil/profil.module#ProfilModule'
  },
```

do i miss something ? Why i cant be redirected to profil and getting logged out of the app instead? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the **`routerLink`** instead of href

```
  <li><a [routerLink]="['/profil']">Profil</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use href?
Angular has routerlink.
Use it like this.

```
routerLink="/profile"
```